# remember the user for several days - cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie to remember users (for a period of 3 days) so they will not have to logon to the website everytime they close their browser.

I've tried the following:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["logind_ok_tjek"]))
 {
     if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`, `rank_hold`, `navn`, `efternavn`, `email_indhold`, `adgangskode`, `rank`, `img` FROM `bruger` WHERE `email_indhold` = ? or tlf = ? AND `adgangskode` = ?"))
     {
         $stmt->bind_param('sss', $email_indhold, $tlf, $adgangskode);
         $email_indhold = $_POST["email"];
         $tlf = $_POST["email"];
         $adgangskode = sha1($_POST["pass"]);


         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->store_result();
         $stmt->bind_result($id, $rank_hold, $navn, $efternavn, $email_indhold, $adgangskode, $rank, $img);
         $stmt->fetch();
         $count = $stmt->num_rows;
         $stmt->close();

         if($count > 0)
         {
             $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
             $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
             $_seesion["rank_hold"] = $rank_hold;
             $_SESSION["navn"] = $navn . " " . $efternavn;
             $_SESSION["rank"] = $rank;
             $_SESSION["img"] = $img;
             $_SESSION["mail"] = $email_indhold;

             setcookie("Navn", $navn . " " . $efternavn, time()+3600);
             setcookie("indhold", $rank_hold, time()+3600);


                 if($_SESSION["logged_in"] == true)
                 {
                     if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `bruger` SET `online_sidste`=? WHERE `id`=?')) {
                         $stmt->bind_param('si', $online_sidste, $id);
                         $online_sidste = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                         $id = $_SESSION["id"];
                         $stmt->execute();
                         echo "Log ind nu!!";
                         $stmt->close();

                     } else {
                         echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
                     }                    
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     echo "Fejl..";    
                 }
         }
         else
         {
             echo "Forkert Email eller password.";
         }
     }
     }
     ?>
```

To access the cookie, I am using:

```
<?php
         echo $_COOKIE["Navn"];
         ?>
```

This is not working, however...

Comment: time+3600.. 3600 is how many seconds to store the cookie. 3600 = one hour.

Comment: Are there any errors in the PHP log?

Comment: and not errors on cookies, @JustinWood

Comment: Im from danmark :) @skrilled so i say 72/3600??

Comment: It should actually be `72*3600`.

Comment: what that ”seesion” is...

Comment: if i say print_r($_COOKIE); so come "Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 3eef1591bb0deb8a513961360f2b1e69 [_ga] => GA1.2.1139435237.1379009588 )" so this error come her

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// set a cookie that expires in 72 hours,you can try with this

```
setcookie("Navn", $navn . " " . $efternavn, time()+3600*72);
setcookie("indhold", $rank_hold, time()+3600*72);
```

`setcookie` function `expire` parameter takes the value in seconds.`time()` will output the current `unix_timestamp`, then you add 3600*72 (3600 seconds * 72 hours) which is equivalent to 3 days (in seconds).

Comment: Thanks for help, :) now I just have done so that it appears on the page.

Comment: if i say print_r($_COOKIE); so come "**Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 3eef1591bb0deb8a513961360f2b1e69 [_ga] => GA1.2.1139435237.1379009588 )**" so this error come her